# Написать функцию, которая выводит на экран ряд чисел Фибоначчи до n. C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, числа-фибоначчи

Нужно написать рекурсивную функцию которая выводит числа Фибоначчи до n. n в функцию передаю в качестве аргумента, должна быть только рекурсия без доп циклов и доп переменных.  Как находить Фибоначчи рекурсивно я знаю.

```
int fib(int n)
{
 if(n < 3)
     return 1;
 return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1);
}
```

Вот я как бы отталкиваюсь от этого кода. Уже и cout в разные места пытался подставить и методом тыка изменял разные значения... не получается(( Помогите пожалуйста. Спасибо!!!

Comment: Так а что не получается?... все работает: https://ideone.com/sJUUN2 Что у вас означает *"числа до `n`"*?

Comment: я передаю n в функцию например n = 5. Мне должно вывести на экран 0 1 1 2 . Только нигде не должно быть доп циклов и переменных ни в мейне ни в самой функции. У и получается функция должна быть void и не возвращать а примерно такой    void fib(int n)
{
 if(n < 3)
    1;
 cout <<  fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1);
}

Comment: Решения с использованем рекурсии крайне не желательно, т.к. сложнасть высокая. Лучше использовать цикл.

Comment: Та я понимаю циклом я умею. А вот задание состоит в том что бы онли рекурсией без доп переменных и циклов.

Comment: точно, не внимательно прочитал

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Задача легко решается, если использовать дополнительную функцию. Хотя на самом деле можно и без нее (если использовать параметры по умолчанию)

```
#include <iostream>

void fib1(int a, int b, int limit)
{
    if (limit == 0) { return; }
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    fib1(b,a+b, limit-1);
}

void fib(int n)
{
    fib1(1,1,n);
}

int main() {
    fib(10);
    return 0;
}
```

данные решение очень "интуитивно", если почитать книги по лиспу:)

Comment: посмотрел внимательно в числа фибоначчи - 48 число уже больше uint32...

Answer (score 4):

(Вариант без (дополнительной функции/переменных) / параметров по умолчанию / циклов)

Напишем функцию `fib` так, что если в неё передаётся положительное число `n`, то она выводит первые `n` чисел Фибоначчи и возвращает `n`-ое число Фибоначчи, а если передаётся отрицательное число `n`, то возвращает `-n`-ое число Фибоначчи (без вывода):

```
int fib(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        // выводим числа Фибоначчи от 1 до n-1
        fib(n - 1);
        // выводим n-ое число Фибоначчи
        cout << (n <= 2 ? 1 : fib(-(n - 1)) + fib(-(n - 2))) << endl;
    } else {
        n *= -1;
    }
    return n <= 2 ? 1 : fib(-(n - 1)) + fib(-(n - 2));
}
```

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/bAutt9)

Comment: очень красиво. :)

Comment: красиво, но только работать будет меееееедленнннно.

Comment: @KoVadim, ну да) мне кажется что ТС скорость не особо важна

Comment: @KoVadim, так задача-то была именно вот так извратиться про рекурсию :) считать подобное рекурсией с точки зрения производительности изначально неверная идея. Исходно, видимо, это учебная задачка на рекурсию. И минимизацию стека в ней. :)

Comment: Если посмотрите на мое решение в откомпилированном виде, то gcc/clang умеют разворачивать хвостовую рекурсию. И стек минимизируется по самое немогу.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fib(int n, bool print=true)
{
  if(n == 2 || n == 1)
  {
    if(print)
       printf("%d\n",1);
    return 1;
  }
  else if(n < 1)
    return 0;
  else
  {
    int res = fib(n - 2, false) + fib(n - 1, true);
    if(print)
        printf("%d\n", res);
    return res;
  }

}

int main()
{
   int N=20;
   fib(N);
}
```

Если я правильно понял, что Вам надо вывести все числа Фиббоначи до `n` БЕЗ циклов.

Comment: и без доп переменных, только рекурсия(((

Comment: А что Вы имеете в виду без доп. переменных? У рекурсивной функции не должно быть никаких аргументов, кроме n?

Comment: да аргумент только один и в теле функции не создавать переменных

Comment: @МаксимТымчак это невозможно. Как минимум временные переменные на стеке будут.